# inject programming code into iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I saw in this article you can run some javascript in a UIWebView:
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview

It would be great if I could inject some business logic into my app based on a few parameters I have or be able to customize it on the fly via the web by downloading updated code that would become part of the app.

has anyone done this or is this even a possibility?

Comment: even if it is possible, does downloading code and running it sound like a good idea? It would have to be signed at a minimum. Plus, I'm sure this contravenes AppStore requirements...

Comment: doesn't this sound more like a job for a web service?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, it contravenes AppStore requirements.

Comment: I didn't even think of it that way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would advise you to avoid doing it. Any app that downloads code will get rejected on the App Store.

From the App Store Review Guidelines:

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected